# class list not working

Tags: c#, list, class

I have taken the advice of many and instead of using Struct, I am using class to create a list

snippets of code

```
class BigClass

class rawData
{
   public string recType;          
   public string ncmCode;  
}
```

i then use streamreader to get data into the object.

```
List<rawData> myData = new List<rawData>();
rawData tempRawData = new rawData();

while ((dataLine = readRawData.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  .....

  for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
  {
    // code to set fields of tempRawData stripped
    ....
  }
  myData.Add(tempRawData);
}
```

This object is added to the List myData but what is happening is when the loop runs again with new tempRawData, it just adds it to myData and replaces what was copied before. So I get 2 rows of the same data... it does this for x rows, so if it runs 10,000 times, the 10,000 rows in the list contain the same data, the data which was read on row 10,000 of the csv file....

Comment: `Add()` do not replace anything, so you are probably messing up with your List.

Comment: I have it declared in the top part of the code. the code is really long, all of works but it does just copies the data to each row the more it moves through the list.

Comment: I think you need to reinitialize tempRawData in every iteration. So use `new` in every loop. At the moment your list will contain multiple references to the same object.

Comment: thats what I thought, I tried, myData.Add(new rawData(tempRawData)) to no evail...

Comment: I've updated your sample to remove unrelated portions - feel free to rollback.

Comment: Just move the declaration of `tempRawData` to inside the for loop; what your code is currently doing is adding the same set of data to the list every single time until `i = tokens.Length`.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<rawData> myData = new List<rawData>();


while ((dataLine = readRawData.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  .....

  for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
  {

    rawData tempRawData = new rawData(); // <======
    // code to set fields of tempRawData stripped
    ....


    myData.Add(tempRawData);
  }
}
```

what your program is currently doing is :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new `RawData` object on each iteration - you are updating fields of the only object you have (which is opposite behavior compared to `struct`):

```
while ((dataLine = readRawData.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  RawData tempRawData = new rawData(); // new for each line iteration.

  ....
  for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
  {
     // set fields of tempRawData here
     ....
  }
  myData.Add(tempRawData);
}
```

Note: you can also keep `RawData tempRawData` outside of `while` and just do new inside on each iteration, but it will extend scope where `tempRawData` is visible for no benefits.

Comment: I get the error "Error 1 'tempRawData' conflicts with the declaration 'WindowsFormsApplication1.ReadCSV.tempRawData'

Comment: remove the original declaration then